# google analytics API - Using cache or "token"?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, token, access-token, google-api-php-client

So my [Google-API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries) is working, but not that well, For example:

- I can perform several queries for sites under one .p12 key.
- And then new several queries for other sites, under another .p12 key.
- so that is OK for several .p12 keys.

But, some times, the second query (second .p12 key) and beyond is just "blocked"... like..  no data...

That is because, the system still using the very first .p12 key.
And that takes at least 1 hour.

After that, the system runs OK for days again.

**So, my question is:** 
*There is some "cache" or "token" in this API that I must "destroy"??*
how to avoid this error?

Comment: I have deleted my answer - as you have noticed I confused a few things, and the method I described is part of the uninstall process for an app (so you better not try this). Sorry about that.

Comment: :) thanks for your attentions anyway!! :D

Comment: Are these calls being made within a browser?  Or from a server?  I noticed you did not include the google-analytics-api tag.

Comment: Hi MS Schenkel, these calls are made by web browser... (thanks for the warning!) But in the future, they will be make by server (terminal php calls) and the browser...

Comment: I try to use `$client->setAccessType("offline");` as I see in [page01](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) and [page02](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) but no success... no errors returned..
**so, the question remains: How to kill or refresh my token?**